# Hide chrome-extension: in "Developer Tools" Scripts tab

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome

When I debug javascript-code in Chrome I use the Scripts tab in the Developer tools. In the list of scripts(the drop-down) a lot of extensions are listed on this form:

- chrome-extension://lfhsdjklfhaslkfhuwklshdfjkash/path/to/script.js
- chrome-extension://lfhsdjklfhaslkfhuwklshdfjkash/path/to/another/script.js
- and so on

I've got around 20-30 such lines and that is pretty annoying when I just want to see my own scripts.

Is it possible to hide these lines but keep the scripts from the current web page?

Comment: These are content scripts injected by extensions, I am not sure if there is any way to hide them ... since these scripts are technically part of the page too ...

Comment: @Madhur Ahuja: I am thinking that since Chrome itself is aware of this there might exist some setting or button somewhere that removes them from view.

Comment: You can try running chrome in incognito mode which will disable the extensions .. this might solve your problem

Comment: @Madhur Ahuja: Yes, that could work in some situations. Thanks.

Comment: What if I don't want to remove the extensions and yet still hide their stuff from developer tools.  For example, I use a jquery inspector that's helpful and an anuglar.js debugger that is also helpful.  Both of these, however, put a plethora of items into the inspector.  I thought there use to be a way to "disable extension input" or something of the sort in the developer tools options.  Anyone have any insight on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chrome now has built in user profile support.  Create yourself a new profile with the extensions you need:  https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2364824?hl=en

<strike>The first option will be to disable all your extensions... not so cool...</strike>

If you find the chrome-extensions scripts very irritating, you can create yourself a developer profile with no extensions (or a minimal set of extensions) for debugging your scripts. Explanation for windows:

- Duplicate your "Google Chrome" shortcut (by ctrl+dragging it)
- Rename the new shortcut to "Chrome Dev Profile".
- Right click it -> Properties
- (Choose a path for your profile dir. You don't need to create it.  For example: c:\users\udi\profiles\chromedevprofile )
- Add to the "Target" field, following the path to chrome.exe:

  `--user-data-dir=c:\users\udi\profiles\chromedevprofile` (with your path of course).
- Launch it (and grab a coffee or wait a minute or so for the hamsters).
- Now you have a second chrome profile running.  You will see there is no history, bookmarks, extensions etc.  Don't panic, you still have all of them in your normal profile.
- Optional:  You would probably want to change the way this chrome looks to get a bit confused.  Install a theme from here: https://tools.google.com/chrome/intl/en/themes/index.html
- Use this profile for debugging. :-)
- (You can also keep your debugging bookmarks in the bookmark toolbar for easy access without disturbing your regular bookmarks toolbar.  Same for debugging oriented extensions.)

Answer (score 3):

(I think the question isn't accurate/relevant today; it's been almost five years. I don't see a “*Scripts* tab” on my Chromium, and there is no drop-down for scripts in the *Sources* tab. In fact, “sources” and “content scripts” appear now separately in *Sources*, and that probably solves the original issue.)

I stumbled upon this question looking for something *very* similar, and I had to figure out the solution, so I'm sharing it for those who arrive here like me:

**How to hide extensions in the *Network* tab**:

Use the [filter text field](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading#filter-requests) to exclude extension scripts. Three ideas:

- `larger-than:1` (best solution).
- If all the resources you care about share protocol: `scheme:https` or `scheme:http`.
- If all the resources you care about come from the same type of TLD: `domain:*.com` (eg).

[image]